# How do I uninstall a language module in Textwrangler?

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, textwrangler, code-editor

I'd like to remove the .m mapping for Objective-C in Textwrangler so that I may have the Matlab syntax highlighting support in the app. I read the users manual and searched online, and both point me to the ~/Library/Application Support/Textwrangler/Language Module folder to delete the said language module. However, when I get to that subfolder, it is empty and has nothing but the new language modules that I installed myself. I also tried unhiding all files in Finder via Terminal commands and still cannot find the language module that I want to delete.

Textwrangler version is 4.5.1 in 10.7.5. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that built-in languages are not in that directory and cannot be removed.
This is not a problem because you can remap the `.m` extension to Matlab files by doing this:

- Go to Preferences -> Languages.
- Add a new "Custom Extension Mapping" and link the suffix `m` to language `Matlab`. I've tested this and it seems to override the default extension mapping.